# Euclidean algorithm pseudocode conversion to Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pseudocode

I have been working on a function for reducing fractions in Swift, and came across the Euclidean algorithm for finding the greatest common factor (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

I converted the pseudo code into swift, but yet I am confused how this is going to give me the greatest common factor if it is returning `a` which I thought was supposed to be the numerator of the fraction. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Pseudocode:**

```
function gcd(a, b)
    while b ≠ 0
       t := b
       b := a mod b
       a := t
     return a
```

**Swift:**

```
var a = 2
var b = 4

func gcd(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    var t = 0
    while b != 0 {
        t = b
        let b = a % b
        let a = t
    }
    return a
}

println("\(a)/\(b)")
```

**Console output:**  2/4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this

```
let b = a % b
```

you are creating another readonly variable `b`, which has nothing to do with the variable `b` from the outside scope. You need to remove both `let`s inside the loop, and make parameters modifiable by declaring them with `var`, like this:

```
func gcd(var a: Int, var b: Int) -> Int {
    var t = 0
    while b != 0 {
        t = b
        b = a % b
        a = t
    }
    return a
}
```

You can call your function like this:

```
let a = 111
let b = 259
println("a=\(a), b=\(b), gcd=\(gcd(a,b))")
```

This prints `a=111, b=259, gcd=37`

Comment: Thank you, this helped! I was caught up at first because I needed to add the keyword `var` before `a:` and `b:` so it doesn't default to `let` variables.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I used a tuple to get rid of `t` in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Taking @dasblinkenlight's answer and getting rid of `t` by using tuples for parallel assignment yields:

**Swift 2.1:**

```
func gcd(var a: Int, var _ b: Int) -> Int {
    while b != 0 {
        (a, b) = (b, a % b)
    }
    return a
}

gcd(1001, 39)  // 13
```

---

`var` parameters are deprecated in **Swift 2.2** and will be removed in **Swift 3**.  So now it becomes necessary to declare `a` and `b` as `var` within the function:

```
func gcd(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    var (a, b) = (a, b)
    while b != 0 {
        (a, b) = (b, a % b)
    }
    return a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version of answer given by Christopher Larsen

```
func gcd(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
  if b == 0 { return a }
  return gcd(a: b, b: a % b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use a recursive method that just keeps calling itself until the GCD is found.

```
func gcd(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    if b == 0 {
        return a
    }

    let remainder: Int = a % b

    return gcd(b, b: remainder)
}
```

and use like so

```
let gcdOfSomeNums = gcd(28851538, b: 1183019)
//gcdOfSomeNums is 17657
```